# Load control style from separate file in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following style added to my Windows.Resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <!--A Style that extends the previous TextBlock Style-->
    <!--This is a "named style" with an x:Key of TitleText-->
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
       TargetType="TextBlock"
       x:Key="TitleText">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#90DDDD" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#5BFFFF" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style> 
    ...
</Window.Resources>
```

I have a lot of those styles in my xaml code and I would like to save each component style to an extra file (not an external file).. for example all the styles related to TextBlocks should be in a file called `TextBlockStyles.xaml`

How would I do this in wpf?

How do I link the style in my project ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29):

You use merged resource dictionaries

In you app.xaml you would use

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary 
                Source="/Your.Assembly.Name;component/TextBlockStyles.xaml"/>
            ... other dictionaries here
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

or directly into a UserControl would be

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary 
                Source="/Your.Assembly.Name;component/TextBlockStyles.xaml"/>
            ... other dictionaries here
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You can shorten `Source="..."` to just `Source="TextBlockStyles.xaml"` if the file is in the same assembly and in the root of the project, or alternatively `Source="Styles\TextBlockStyles.xaml"` if you put the resource dictionary into the folder `Styles`.

Comment: So what does the file called `TextBlockStyles.xaml` look like?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: An example [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#merged-resource-dictionaries). (It is called `Dictionary1.xaml` in this example.)

Comment: Don't forget to add a reference to the dll the style is defined in.

Answer (score 6):

Use case: you have a user control called `MyView.xaml` with a button.  You want to style the button with an external XAML file.

---

In `MyView.xaml`:

```
<User Control ...namespaces...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            ...converters...

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MyButton.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

     ...the rest of the control...
</UserControl>
```

In `MyButton.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MSDNSample">

    <Style x:Key="FooButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Back to `MyView.xaml` ("the rest of the control"):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource FooButton}">
    Hello World
</Button>
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Solution Explorer** Right Click on your **Project** Select **Add** After that click on **Resource Dictionary...**
Choose name and add to your project.
Open **App.xaml**
Add This Code in **Application** Tag

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="YourStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In YourStyle.xaml :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:APPNAME">
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the dynamic resources. well the best way is to load and marge the dictionary in the resources. application or either on control page. 
here is a good sample for it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/06/08/defining-and-using-shared-resources-in-a-custom-control-library.aspx

```
<ResourceDictionary>

  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>

  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Smyresourcedictionary);

Answer (score 1):

Simply, go to your Window (example: `MaindWindow.xaml`) where you want to include the resource from the outer file and use [MergedDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries) principle to refer to that file:

```cs
<Window x:Class="UseMergedResource.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="600"
        Width="600">
  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- DECLARING MERGED DICTIONARY --> 
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source='Merged/BrushResources.xaml' />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <!----------------------------------> 

  </Window.Resources>


  <StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Width='200'
               Height='100'
               Fill='{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}' /> <!-- USAGE HERE -->
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

> From above `Merged/BrushResources.xaml` is the location of the resource file, which is located under the folder called `Merged`.

Now if you are wondering what should be the declaration syntax in the outer file, check this:

```cs
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- Location for application brushes -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key='BorderBrush'
                                     Color='Orange' />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key='HighLightBrush'
                                     Color='LightBlue' />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key='PrimaryBrush'
                                     Color='Pink' />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key='AccentBrush'
                                     Color='Yellow' />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

> If you want to make the resource available through all application (visible in all your windows) then declare in the `App.xaml` resources section.

Comment: Note that if you have resources already in your `<Window.Resources>` section, they should go inside `<ResourceDictionary>`, e.g. just before the `</ResourceDictionary>` line.